# ajax sum total number of VIEWS

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, joomla

I have a statistic on my page which shows the TOTAL NUMBER OF ARTICLE VIEWS...

here is the code I wrote to have the total number of views:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();

$total_views = "SELECT SUM(times_viewed) FROM #__hdflv_upload";
$db->setQuery($total_views);
$result = $db->loadResult();
```

What I'm trying to achieve is, UPDATE this total number of Views AJAX on page, so if I get for example +10 views in the last 5 seconds, the total number of views must SUM +10 AJAX... without page reload....

I searched in google etc.. but didn't find nothing close to this that can help me... can somebody PLEASE give me a hand. THANK YOU VERY MUCH.

Answer (score 0):

On your statistic page, you could set a JS timer which uses [`.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to get the SQL results every 5 seconds.  The script it calls can return the query result in JSON format, then update your DOM accordingly.

There's a pretty good answer at [Joomla Stackexchange](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/146/what-is-the-proper-way-to-make-an-ajax-call-in-component) which should help you get a Joomla AJAX call working properly to run the SQL and return the result.